# How can I retrieve all rows which depend on other rows in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

So I have this table scheme

`|id| item_id | dependency_item_id | completed |`

The idea is to have rows in this table to point to other rows in the same table by dependency_item_id -> item_id.

What I want is to retrieve all records which have a `dependency_item_id` with a value of `NULL` and `completed` with a value of 0

AND

All records which have their parent, row which is the one with the `item_id = dependency_item_id`, with status `completed = 1` and their status `completed = 0`

Example:

```
These are the records in the database.
|id|task_id|dependency_item_id|completed|
|1 |1      |null              |1        |
|2 |2      |null              |0        |
|3 |3      |1                 |0        |
|4 |4      |2                 |0        |
|5 |5      |2                 |0        |

With the query we should get only the second record
|id|task_id|dependency_item_id|completed|
|2 |2      |null              |0        |
|3 |3      |1                 |0        |
```

The query I have by this point is the following:

```
SELECT process.* 
    FROM tasks AS tasks 
        JOIN tasks AS dep ON dep.dependency_item_id = process.task_id 
    WHERE (dep.completed = 1 and tasks.completed = 0) OR tasks.dependency_item_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Join the table with itself.

Comment: When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can self-join the table:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
left join mytable d on d.id = t.dependency_item_id
where 
    (t.dependency_item_id is null and t.completed = 0)
    or (d.dependency_item_id is null and d.completed = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the case where you would require a correlated subquery.

```
Select * from items as I where (dependency_item is null and completed = 0 )
OR 
item_id in (Select item_id from items as S where I.dependency_item = S.item_id and
I.completed = 0 and S.completed = 1)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak the queries you gave me to suit my need because with the given queries I couldn't retrieve the records which had null dependencies. My final result was the following:

```
SELECT dep.* 
    FROM tasks AS task 
        LEFT JOIN tasks AS dep ON dep.dependency_item_id = task.item_id 
    WHERE (task.completed = 1 and dep.completed = 0) 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE dependency_item_id IS NULL AND completed = 0
```